# Signing into a website using Microsoft Account

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have been reading [this page "Guidelines for the Microsoft account sign-in experience (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh968445.aspx) and I would also like my users to be able to sign into my *website* using their Microsoft Account.

But I have yet to find a website with documentation on signing into sites using Microsoft accounts. Could somebody please point me in the right direction? Any tutorials/other resources would also  be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx

Answer (score 0):

have a look on here for dotnetopenauth questions or visit www.dotnetopenauth.net. Microsoft Accounts can be used as OpenId accounts. There is also a nuget package that wraps up using well-know providers, such as Live ID, Google, Yahoo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe are you looking for this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn659751.aspx